# scala testing values of against different types

Tags: scala

Sorry for the newbie question. Is there an equivalent scala idiom to Python code where I can test for a value of different types?

```
  if value in ['true', True, "1", 1]:
    ret_value = True
  elif value in ['false', False, "0", 0]:
    ret_value = False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idiomatic Scala generally avoids variables that can be of any type, and so most Scala programmers would avoid this situation.  It does come up once in a while, though.  You could do:

```
val truthies = Set(true, 1, "1", "true") // Set[Any], a type that would generally be avoided
truthies("true") //true
truthies(1) //true
truthies("foo") //false
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. It would not make a lot of sense, since your `value` variable has a fixed type. As such, 3 out of your 4 possible values will never work, and the compiler knows it.

That said, if you have a set of possible values of the same type, you can always use `List(1, 2, 3, 4).contains(value)`

The real beauty of a strongly typed language is that it make a whole **category** of errors **impossible**! So you don't need to code that defensively.

Comment: That's what I thought, but just in case I missed something.. Thx

Comment: I'd recommend a `Set` though. In the case of 4 items, it doesn't matter. But it's a good idea to form the habit, because for larger cases, it makes the difference between O(n) and O(n*log(n)).

Comment: I'm afraid this is potentially misleading. Scala is perfectly happy to infer a type for e.g. `List("true", true, "1", 1)`, and there's no reason you can't use `contains` on the result.

Comment: True, forgot about that! But you'll force the compiler to a common parent type. Like List[Any]. Which kind of defeats the purpose of a type system. So unless you have a very specific scenario in mind and can't do it more elegantly, I would discourage that kind of thinking. Actually, that is the reason I forgot that option in the first place ;-)

Comment: In particular, the example seems to be validating against "all possible false values". No need in Scala, an if for instance will not accept 1 as a valid parameter. There is only the Boolean class.